# HTML file input dialogue not showing files list

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am using html file input to prompt file dialog for upload but somehow it is stuck at opening the file explorer. What can cause this to happen?



```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#fileId').click();">Upload</a>
<input type="file" id="fileId" style="display:none">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please enter
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide and run the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="fileId" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="$('#fileId').click();">Upload</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Your code for me is working,
So the problem must be in another place
Please check console.
Please run code on another browser.